# How can I prevent unwanted GET requests with URLs added to parameters

Tags: nginx, fail2ban

I have a small ecommerce site, (LEMP stack) and I had used a route like

`my.domain.com/makecart?return_url=....`

as a means of returning to a point in the previous page to assist selection for the cart.

Over a period of months I started getting thousands of `GET` requests with unwanted domain links appended to the `?return_url` parameter.

I have now reprogrammed this route without the use of any parameters, but my site is still getting the unwanted hits.

```
e.g. 76.175.182.173 - - [14/Nov/2018:19:36:08 +0000] "GET /makecart?return_url=http://www.nailartdeltona.com/ HTTP/1.0" 302 364 "http://danielcraig.2bb.ru/click.php
```

I am redirecting such requests to an error page, and have it 'under control' with `fail2ban` but I am gradually filling up memory with banning information.

Is there a way to prevent these hits before they are plucked back out of the access log?

Furthermore what are they doing anyway?